# CoreData fetch request - complex predicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, key-value-coding

How would I simplify this using (ideally) a single predicate with key-value coding collection operators? (The array of interest in the end is `filteredGames`.)

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Game" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSArray *games = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

NSMutableArray *filteredGames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (Game *game in games) {
    NSInteger maxRoundNumber = [game.rounds valueForKeyPath:@"@max.number"];
    Round *maxRound = [[game.rounds filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number = %d", maxRoundNumber]] anyObject];
    if (maxRound.someBoolProperty)
        [filteredGames addObject:game];
}
```

Game has an `NSSet` property `rounds` of `Rounds`, and `Round` has an `NSInteger` property `number`, and I'm looking for those `Games` whose highest-number `Round` has some `BOOL` property `someBoolProperty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Game"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SUBQUERY(rounds, $r, $r.someBoolProperty = YES).number = @max.rounds.number"];
```

Comment: thanks, martin. didn't know about subqueries, apparently there's little documentation except in an entry in the NSExpression ref